How to find the cell with 2 matching fields in the same row in excel?
Very similar to the example below. However, I don't want to specifically looking for particular ID. Let's say item is T-shirt, and I change the color from Black to Blue. The Price cell would immediately reflect to that and update to $17.5. Is this doable with formula? I found an example to use index + match but was only able to make it to work with one value.


There are many questions solved here with such type similar questions. Please try do search. Also you can try: =INDEX(DATA[Price],MATCH(1,(F2=DATA[Item])*(G2=DATA[Color]),0)) <-- Consider you have Table as shown in the screenshot named as DATA and you'r lookup values are Item and Color do a boolean logic comparison to get the position of the said item and then return the value using INDEX(). Note that this doesn't accounts for the ID this wouldn't have worked and returned as an error. it is completely based on Items and color

Also it is better to use XLOOKUP() here --> =XLOOKUP(1,(F2=DATA[Item])*(G2=DATA[Color]),DATA[Price],"") Refer this post here

All these below formulas should work-
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C12)*(A2:A12=F2)*(B2:B12=G2))
=XLOOKUP(1,(A2:A12=F2)*(B2:B12=G2),C2:C12)
=FILTER(C2:C12,(A2:A12=F2)*(B2:B12=G2))


